# How do make a list that is always remembered?

Tags: python, list, file, memory

I have been making name_of_list.txt documents every time I want to store information to be remembered later. However, I feel like there is a more efficient way to remember a list than to scan a document, see if a word is already there, and if not, add it at the end. Here is the code that I generally use for this:

```
def noun_dict(word):  # Searches to see if the word is already a noun, if not, adds it.
    from string import ascii_letters
    nouns = []
    with open("word_types_nouns.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        x = 0
        for line in lines:  # Notice 'words' is different than 'word'
            words = [word for word in line.split() if all(ch in ascii_letters for ch in word)]
            x += 1
            nouns.append(words[0])
        nouns.sort()
        if nouns.count(word) == 0:
            nouns.append(word)
            with open("word_types_nouns.txt", "a") as file:
                file.write("\n" + str(word))
            print(word[0].capitalize() + word[1:], "added as a noun.")
        else:
            print(word[0].capitalize() + word[1:], "already identified as a noun.")
        return nouns
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Comment: @alfasin I am unfamiliar with pickle. Is there any code you know that you would be willing to share?

Comment: Search google for pickle examples - you'll find tons...

Comment: Ick, don't use pickle. Use `json` or some other safe method.

Comment: Nothing to do with saving data to a file, but...  It looks like the data structure you want is not a `list` but a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).  It already does exactly the things you're doing, and faster too.  (Check the "Common patterns" section before the grey "Note:" box for more examples.)